MSIX Setup Not Launching Properly; App Opens in Background Without Visible Window
MSIX Setup Not Launching Properly; App Opens in Background Without Visible Window


Question:
I've developed a Flutter desktop app that works fine when run directly from the executable file in the release folder. My app uses a local SQLite database stored in the same release folder, and it also includes images and fonts in the assets directory.
However, when I create an MSIX package and install it, the app opens but only in the background—there’s no visible window on launch, with one specific line change in the CMake file, it launches but only displays a white screen.
Has anyone encountered this issue? Any insights on what might be causing the app to run in the background without showing the main window, and how to fix it for MSIX?
1 SQL.dll is in the release folder present
2 I used relative path for images
